# Error "certificate signed by unknown authority" after switching GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

After switching gcloud projects using ...

```
gcloud init
```

... and then try to do some kubectl command, like this for instance:

```
kubectl get rc
```

... I get this error:

```
error: couldn't read version from server: Get
https://130.211.59.254/api: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Why is this and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 16):

This is because the keys to your old cluster is cached. I'm not sure why they are not updated by the gcloud init command (that's what one would intuitively expect, or at least some kinder error message from kubectl)

You solve it by simply getting the credentials of the cluster in the new configuration:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials YOURCLUSTERHERE --zone YOURCLUSTERZONEHERE
```

Comment: `gcloud init` only configures authentication for the GKE API endpoint, not a particular cluster (since you may have multiple clusters in a single project).

Comment: It's 2021 and this is still happening in GKE. Thank's for the answer. Where the answer suggests YOURCLUSTERHERE is YOURPROJECTHERE, because this parameter is the project id.

Comment: Thank you Matthias and Laercio. The correct command is actually:
`gcloud container clusters get-credentials YOURCLUSTERHERE YOURPROJECTHERE --zone YOURCLUSTERZONEHERE`

Answer (score 2):

This can be resolved by fetching the credential

**gcloud container clusters get-credentials   < container-cluster >    --zone < zone >  --project   < project name >**

Or

login to GCP

GCP -> container engine -> container clusters -> connect to cluster

Refer this docs for further information

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials

Answer (score 0):

step 1:
Remove .kube/config file

step 2:
gcloud container clusters get-credentials YOURCLUSTERHERE

Still, if you facing issue, then disconnect with your current orgnization network and try with mobile hotspot or your wifi.