# kubectl x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We have running instance on GKE. Till this afternoon we started to receive "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" error from new created kubernetes cluster. The kubectl is working with old clusters but not with new ones.

---

**What we tried:**

- gcloud update
- kubectl update
- gcloud re authenticate
- clean gcloud install & auth
- .kube/config cert remove & gcloud container clusters get-credentials
- remove and add new clusters

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "certificate signed by unknown authority" after switching GCP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029270/error-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-after-switching-gcp-project)